# Store nested data with files with vuejs & laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, file-upload

I have a form which holds information about few entities: citizen, passport, passport scan.

I need to save the citizen with its relationships, and at the same time upload passport scans which are images.

I ended up with having an object on the client side which looks like this:

[image]

However I don't know how to store scans, since I couldn't get anything from laravel's `$request->file(...)` method (it returns null).

In my case all of these entities have to be consistent, I mean there shouldn't be any case when I've stored citizen without passport or passport without scan.

So I'm not sure how to store scans in this case, since I cannot use nested data in formData objects for example.

Comment: Base64 is not in the request file, you have to read the string and convert it back to the image `$request->get('foreignCitizen.passports[0].scans[0]')`. 
An other option is to store the person and latter on submit the passport files with FormData so `POST /person/1/scans` will attach the documents to person 1.

Comment: I thought about separating requests into 1. store person 2. store passport 3. store passport scan, but was wondering what if I need to keep these 3 queries consistent, like, there shouldn't be any situation when scan is not loaded (for example connection has been lost). 
Not sure I got you about converting string to image, okay, I can get the string, but how to convert it to image (or generally to any file, so that laravel could just determine mime-type and other stuff)

Answer (score 0):

Base64 is not in the request file, you have to read the string and convert it back to the image `$request->get('foreignCitizen.passports[0].scans[0]')`. An other option is to store the person and latter on submit the passport files with FormData so POST /person/1/scans will attach the documents to person 1.

With this validator you can validate the images.

```
    Validator::extend('image64',function($attribute, $base64Data, $mimeTypes, $validator) {
        // strip out data uri scheme information (see RFC 2397)
        if (strpos($base64Data, ';base64') !== false) {
            [$_, $base64Data] = explode(';', $base64Data);
            [$_, $base64Data] = explode(',', $base64Data);
        }

        // strict mode filters for non-base64 alphabet characters
        if (base64_decode($base64Data, true) === false) {
            return false;
        }

        // decoding and then reeconding should not change the data
        if (base64_encode(base64_decode($base64Data)) !== $base64Data) {
            return false;
        }

        $image = base64_decode($base64Data);
        $file  = finfo_open();
        $type  = finfo_buffer($file, $image, FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);

        return in_array($type, $mimeTypes);
    });
```

> Inspired by [Spatie media lib](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-medialibrary/blob/1e4fbaf0d439919b8e79605db65872a3b1aba8f1/src/HasMedia/HasMediaTrait.php#L161)

`foreignCitizen.passports.*.scans.*.data => 'required|base64:image/jpeg'`.
Now we have a valid base64 image, we can store this safely.

I like to use [Spatie media library](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-medialibrary) the have a method `addMediaFromBase64()`.
You can also do it manually converting the base64 string and storing it as a file.

If you choose to split up the process, first store the person and then the image. This is probably a bit easier to implement and less code on the backend.

Answer (score 0):

I ran across this exact same problem just yesterday and finally I have a solution. Here it is:

Laravel documentation doesn't say or at least I could not find it, but you can also access the uploaded file just like any other field, eg: $reques->uploadedFile and use it to store it like this

```
Storage::putFile('public', $request->uploadedFile);
```

So in your example you can store the scans like this:

```
Storage::putFile('public', $request->foreignCitizen['passports'][0]['scans'][0]);
```

That in general, surely you know how to apply some for loops to make it more manageable.

PS: You don't mention if you already have sorted out the part of sending the object with the nested files to laravel, but like I said, I was in the exact same problem (vuejs/laravel), if you still haven't solve that, I can help with that too.